# New to Grunt - Can't find any tasks

Tags: javascript, node.js, task, npm, gruntjs

I have followed the Getting started guide at http://gruntjs.com/getting-started, but I can't seem to run grunt (running grunt-cli v0.1.9 and grunt 0.4.1 on Mac OS X 10.8.5, installed with npm).

This is my Gruntfile.js:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.registerTask('test', 'Test task.', function() {
        grunt.log.writeln('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.');
    });
};
```

When I try to run grunt with "grunt test" I just get:

```
Warning: Task "test" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

I have also tried installing plugins like uglify (following the examples in Getting started), but no tasks seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your Gruntfile.js is okay. Grunt-cli seems to work, too. Make sure that grunt is installed locally to your project or try to setup a "clean" new grunt project.

Comment: Ok, that actually worked. This is what I did:
cd ..
**mkdir grunt-test**
**cd grunt-test/**
**nano Gruntfile.js**
**grunt test**
Running "test" task
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

Done, without errors.

Comment: I'm trying to run grunt on a project thats based on Laravel (with composer). Could that interfere with grunt in some way?

Comment: I don't think so. Do you have a npm package.json file for your grunt dependencies in your project-directory?

Comment: Yes, created it after looking at the example at gruntjs.com. It consists of name, version and devDependencies (grunt, grunt-contrib and grunt-ember-templates). I've tried running npm install, which creates the folder node_modules with grunt, grunt-contrib and grunt-ember-templates.

Comment: Oh, it works now. Just before I ran npm install I removed the old node_modules directory. Now I can run grunt test just fine. Thanks!